# Disallow user access but allow script/cron access

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cron

I have some files I want to run via cron, but I don't want users or SE's being able to access them - I tried storing them in a non-web accessible directory but that caused problems with including of some other files.

So if I store them in a web-accessible dir, how can I make it so cron can run the script but users and SE's can't access them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume those PHP files are in a directory `DOCUMENT_ROOT/scripts` then add this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+scripts/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

This will show forbidden error for any web request for `/scripts` but will allow your cron job to access them (assuming cron is executing it from command line using `php -f`)

To block access to all `.php` file in sub/subdir, put this code in `sub/subdir/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s+/+.+?\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Comment: I'm thinking now it's because the folder that contains the files is a sub-dir of a sub-dir. Couldn't I just put the .htaccess file in the folder itself and do something like: `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s+/*\.php [NC]` ?

Comment: Yes that be done also. I will provide you right syntax in my answer.